# Creating an automatic generated worksheet menu

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with fine tuning my VBA for an automatic generated worksheet menu. So far I have the following;

```
Dim objSheet As Worksheet

Worksheets("General Information").Activate
Range("W14").Select

For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> objSheet.Name Then
       ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & objSheet.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=objSheet.Name
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
       ActiveCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If
Next objSheet
```

This works perfectly. However, I would like to have a fixed starting point as the first few sheets are always the same.
In other words I need this to work as of the 12th worksheet onwards.

Can you please help me out with this addition, thanks

Comment: Do you have the first 11 worksheet names written in a range on worksheet `General Information` e.g. in range `B3:B13` ? If you could share the location, I would like to present a an approach which would allow you to freely change the position of the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```vb
Const intSheetStart As Integer = 12
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim objSheet As Worksheet

Worksheets("General Information").Activate
Range("W14").Select

intCount = 0

For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    intCount = intCount + 1

    If intSheetStart <= intCount Then
       If ActiveSheet.Name <> objSheet.Name Then
          ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & objSheet.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=objSheet.Name
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
          ActiveCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
       End If
    End If
Next objSheet
```

This change sets the starting point in a constant, then counts the sheets and only runs the rest of the code if the current sheet is the starting point or after.

Answer (score 0):

A different way of controlling it, is using another kind of loop, and set a starting point in the code.

```
For i = 12 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=Worksheets(i).Name
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Next i
```

This starts the count at the 12th sheet as noted by `i= 12` and then goes to the last sheet `Worksheets.Count`.

Also it's generally good practice to not select things, so here is a version without selecting a cell:

```
Sub links()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("General Information")

For i = 12 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i + 2, 23), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=Worksheets(i).Name
Next i
Cells(1, 23).EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

And for a more dynamic approach, as inspired by sbgib:

```
Sub menu()
Dim ws As Worksheet, printRow As Long, startCol As Long

Const startSheet As Long = 12   '- Which sheet number to start from
printCol = 23                   '- Column "W" is column number 23
printRow = 14                   '- First row to add hyperlinks to

Set ws = Worksheets("General Information")
printRow = printRow - startSheet
For i = startSheet To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(printRow + i, printCol), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=Worksheets(i).Name
Next i
Cells(1, printCol).EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```